# Quiero unir 3 consultas con sus filtros en una sola en SQL

Tags: sql-server-2017

Quisiera unir estas 3 en una sola, ya intenté usar UNION o JOIN pero siempre me salta error debido a que no tienen el mismo número de expresiones en sus listas de destino.

```
SELECT ano_codano AS 'Año',mes_codmes AS 'Mes', vfecvenpag AS 'Fecha', vapenomrso AS 'Empresa', tdo_codtdo AS 'Tipo de venta', tcc_numdoc, tcc_codepk
FROM dbo.LE_REGISTRO_VENTAS_2
WHERE vfecvenpag between '20180501' and '20180512' and ano_codano = '2018' and mes_codmes = '5'


SELECT ano_codano AS 'Año', mes_codmes AS 'Mes', tdo_codtdo AS 'Tipo de venta', tcc_numdoc,  tcc_codepk
FROM dbo.TRAN_CTACTE_TCC
WHERE ano_codano = '2018' and mes_codmes = '5'


SELECT tdc_nomaux, tcc_codepk, tdc_feccre
FROM dbo.TRAN_DOCCOB_TDC 
WHERE tdc_feccre between '20180501' and '20180512'
```

Answer (score -1):

Si deseas realizar union las columnas de los 3 select's deben coincidir en el nro y nombre de columnas, por ejemplo así:

```
SELECT ano_codano AS 'Año',mes_codmes AS 'Mes', vfecvenpag AS 'Fecha', vapenomrso AS 'Empresa', tdo_codtdo AS 'Tipo de venta', tcc_numdoc, 
tcc_codepk,'' AS tdc_nomaux,'' AS tcc_codepk, '' AS tdc_feccre 
FROM dbo.LE_REGISTRO_VENTAS_2 
WHERE vfecvenpag between '20180501' and '20180512' and ano_codano = '2018' and mes_codmes = '5'
union all
SELECT ano_codano AS 'Año', mes_codmes AS 'Mes',vfecvenpag AS 'Fecha', '' AS 'Empresa',  '' AS 'Tipo de venta', tcc_numdoc, tcc_codepk,
'' AS tdc_nomaux,'' AS tcc_codepk, '' AS tdc_feccre 
FROM dbo.TRAN_CTACTE_TCC WHERE ano_codano = '2018' and mes_codmes = '5'
union all
SELECT ano_codano AS 'Año',mes_codmes AS 'Mes', vfecvenpag AS 'Fecha', vapenomrso AS 'Empresa', tdo_codtdo AS 'Tipo de venta', 
tcc_numdoc, tcc_codepk '' AS tdc_nomaux,'' AS tcc_codepk, '' AS tdc_feccre 
FROM dbo.TRAN_DOCCOB_TDC WHERE tdc_feccre between '20180501' and '20180512'
```

Comment: El usuario ya indica que no coinciden el numero de columnas por lo que esta solución no le sirve para nada.

Comment: Por eso en el ejemplo puede agregar las columnas que tiene en el otro select y poder ejecutar su resultado y unificar todo.

Comment: Eso es una chapuza.